# Model Customer preferences with different Products for Sellers

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I have a model where `Sellers` can sell `Products` to `Customers`. `Sellers` need to be able to set `Preferences` for `Customers` on a specific `Product`. I can see how that may be confusing so let me give an example.

The `Seller` is selling `Shoes`, so he wants to set specific `Shoes` preferences for `Customer` x (colour, material, brand, size, etc), so that when `Customer` x visits the page, a `Shoe` with that colour and sizes is shown to the `Customer`. That logic is not the important thing right now. I just want to know how would you build the object model, given that requirements. I thought on having a list of `Preferences` in the `Customer` class,

```
class Customer
{
    public List<ShoePreferences> ShoePreferences {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

but that is problematic, given that the `Customer` can have lots of them, for different `Products` and for different `Sellers`.

I'm following Domain Driven Design techniques, so clearly I'm not going to make a relational model and build the object model based on that.

Can you give me some guidance in this? Any comment is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the DDD point of view the first thing that you need to identify is the Bounded context where this functionality should reside. Next are the business invariants, if any. After all these strategic analysis you can move forward to tactical decisions like what Aggregates, Entities and Value objects to build.

From what I see this functionality should stay in a `UI`,  `Presentation` or `Session` sub-bounded context as it is something specific to the User eXperience domain. It does not change the way the Ordering or the Inventory work.

I don't see any complex business invariants that must be protected.

So, this new feature should reside in a new module or sub-module or namespace. A simple [CRUD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) entity should suffice: `CustomerShoePreferences` with references to the `CustomerId` and `ProductId` and with Value objects that quantitatively  describe the entity (color, size etc).

As you can see, although you haven't use the full arsenal of DDD bulding blocks , like Aggregates, the strategic design of DDD can help you to find the best architecture for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just have one more question. If the entity Preferences had to be a separate entity (ShoePreferences), so that the seller can configure the values ​​independently of a Customer, the CustomerShoePreferences class would be added a ShoePreferencesId right? Thanks!

Comment: @user70014 most probable but you should be able to also load it by (customerId x productId)

Answer (score 1):

I am still not very clear with requirement though, but i can understand pain of having `ShoePreference` as part of `Customer` Better to come up with some generic modeling. I can visualize something like below :

```
IPreference{

Dictionary<string, List<NameVauePair>> GetPreference();} 

/*ex : shoes, new List{ new NameValuePair{Name = "Color" , Value="Black"} */


class Customer
{
    public List<IPreference> Preferences {get; set;}
    ...
}

PreferenceEvaluator(customer cust){

var preferences = cust.GetPreference();
/* logic to match preference */}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation where some thought about the relational model might actually help you. The simplest solution will be to store all preferences in a single table where a `Preference` entity will have a natural composite key on `[customerId]`, `[sellerId]`, `[productId]`, and `[preferenceName]`. If storing a hierarchy of preferences for a single attribute (e.g. Black -> Blue -> Red), you may need to add another field to the key: `[rank]`. There are other possibilities involving table hierarchies, but they would naturally lead to the very domain model you are trying to avoid.

So with the above in mind, the most obvious implementation is to have a single `List<Preference>` injected into each `Customer` that can be filtered according to any one of the attributes listed above.